# input value returns NaN on ng-click

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am writing a program that takes in input value for two numbers and provides a random value from the range specified. I have fixed controllers to shuffle min and max value and it works once i place numbers but if i add the ng-model value, it returns "NaN". Here is the html

```
        <div class="col-sm-4" ng-controller="ValueController">

          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-6"><input type="number" ng-model="value.one">
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-6"><input ng-model="value.two"></div>
          </div>   
        </div>

        <div class="col-sm-4">

            <a ng-href="results.html" ng-controller="ShuffleController" 
            ng-click="shuffle(100100, 110000)">
        <img src="img/before.png" style="width: 500px; height: auto;"></a>
          </ul>

        </div>
```

Here is part of the app.js:

```
    // Angular App Initialization
var app = angular.module('Shuffle', ['ngRoute']);

// Declaring Globals
app.run(function($rootScope) {

    $rootScope.shuffled = [];
    $rootScope.shuffleValues = {};

    $rootScope.getRand = function(min, max) {
      var number = Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min)) + min;
      var leadingZeroes = 6 - number.toString().length;
      $rootScope.shuffled.push([[min, max], number.toString().length < 6 ? ('0'.repeat(leadingZeroes) + number) : number]);
      window.localStorage.setItem('shuffled', JSON.stringify($rootScope.shuffled));
    }
});

// Shuffle Controller
app.controller('ShuffleController', function($scope, $rootScope, $window) {
  console.log('Welcome to TheShuffler!');
  var results = window.localStorage.getItem('shuffled');
  results = JSON.parse(results);
  $scope.shuffle = function(min, max) {
    console.log("You shuffled!");
    console.log(results);
    $rootScope.getRand(min, max);
  }
});

// Results Controller
app.controller('ResultsController', function($scope) {
  var results = window.localStorage.getItem('shuffled');
  $scope.shuffleResults = JSON.parse(results);
  $scope.quantity = 3;
  console.log($scope.shuffleResults);
});

// Reshuffling Controller
app.controller('ReshuffleController', function($scope, $rootScope, $route, $window, $location) {
  $scope.reshuffle = function(){
    $window.location.reload();
    console.log('You reshuffled!');
    var results = window.localStorage.getItem('shuffled');
    results = $scope.shuffleResults = JSON.parse(results);

    for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
      var min = results[i][0][0]
      var max = results[i][0][1]
      $rootScope.getRand(min, max)
    }
  }
});

// Shuffle Entries Verification Controller
app.controller('ShuffleEntriesVerificationController', function($scope, $window) {
  console.log('EntriesHere!');
  $scope.entryCheck = function(){
    var results = window.localStorage.getItem('shuffled');
    results = JSON.parse(results);
    console.log("You checked!");
    console.log(results);
    var verficationMessage = "Maximum Entries Exceeded. Please Click Shuffle";
    if (results.length > 2) {
      $window.alert(verficationMessage);
      $window.location.reload();
    }
  }
});

app.controller('ValueController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
          $scope.value = {
            one: 000100,
            two: 005100
          };

        }]);


it('should check ng-bind', function() {
  var nameInput = element(by.model('value'));

  expect(element(by.binding('value')).getText()).toBe('Whirled');
  nameInput.clear();
  nameInput.sendKeys('world');
  expect(element(by.binding('value')).getText()).toBe('world');
});
```

I get NaN when i do this:

```
<a ng-href="results.html" ng-controller="ShuffleController" 
ng-click="shuffle(value.one, value.two)">
<img src="img/before.png" style="width: 500px; height: auto;"></a>
```

What is the problem?

Comment: code on plunker pls

Comment: [create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Added what is missing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a wrong controller:

```
ng-controller="ShuffleController"
```

while in your app you have this controller:

```
app.controller('ValueController',...
    ...
}]);
```

Comment: it could have thrown the controller not found error.

Comment: And also he could check the tag elements starting point and end point with a controller and $scope objects.

Comment: @kailashyogeshwar might be! can't say what OP has in it's code. This is just a noticeable thing of whatever OP has posted.

Comment: @Jai agree a snippet would be helpful

Comment: @kailashyogeshwar It could be also possible that OP might have a nested controllers.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to pass the model as parameter values will be automatically bound and available in your shuffle function.

In case of your NaN error create a snippet to get a better perspective of your problem